# Can you provide recommendations on how to debug "Positive directional derivative for linesearch"?

Tags: openmdao

I've been trying to get a dynamic optimization working using dymos, but my optimizations routinely fail with the following error: "Positive directional derivative for linesearch".
From what I understand, this error is common if the optimizer cannot identify a feasible solution because of constraint violations or poor variable scaling. My questions are below.

1. How would you recommend debugging this error for a dymos problem? Specifically, how would I determine which constraints are not satisfied? I'm aware that the driver has a debugging option for printing constraints, but for dymos problems, I have hundreds of constraints and that information is a nightmare to parse.
2. I checked the scaling report using `p.driver.scaling_report()` and many of the dymos collocation and continuity constraints have very poor scaling (I'm looking for the scaled value to be on the order of 1). I've provided the constraints output of the scaling report below. How do you recommend setting ref for the collocation_constraint and continuity_comp constraints? Is it typical to have those constraints scaled in the same way as the design variables? Can scaling even be applied to the continuity_comp constraints?

If the extra information helps, I'm using the SciPyOptimize Driver with SLSQP optimizer. Thanks in advance.

[image: Scaling Report]

Comment: Is your initial guess for your state variables within the bounds?  This could mean SLSQP is outside the feasible region or is perhaps in a flat region of the optimization (none of the variables are impacting the gradient much).

Have you run `prob.check_totals()` to verify that they are correct?

Comment: Yes. All initial guesses for states, controls, and parameters are well within their bounds.

Comment: OpenMDAO does return a warning that `....phase0.time.time,inds=[29]` and `...path_constraints.path:Airframe_x1', inds=[(0, 0)])]` cannot be impacted by the design variables, but I expect that for how I define the problem. `check_partials()` are good with relative error order <=10^-6. I have just tried `p.check_totals()` and some of those have relative error order <= 10^-2. I assume that is an issue? I'm very confident my analytical partials are correct. Any ideas why the totals are off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> check_partials() are good with relative error order <=10^-6

Sometimes you can have good looking partials around your initial contidition, but they are incorrect when you move away to another point. Often this happens if you defaulted an input to 0 or set an initial condition to 1 and that creates a special case where derivatives simplify and your mistakes get hidden. As an extra double sanity check, I suggest you add a small bit of random noise to at least a few of your inputs and double check your partials.

Its pretty rare for `check_totals` with FD to tightly match the analytic models, so a small bit of error is expected. You could try switching to `CS` for the totals. Things should match well then, unless there is a complex-step problem non compatible calculation somewhere in your code.

Another possibilility is that you have an incorrect linear solver setup in your model somewhere. Do you have any [NonLinearBlockGS](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.17.0/features/building_blocks/solvers/nonlinear_block_gs.html) solvers in your model? If yes, did you also add a linear solver to that same group (probably a [DirectSolver](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.17.0/features/building_blocks/solvers/direct_solver.html)).

If you show us a XDSM zoomed into your ODE, we can sanity check it. If you can post a gist of your model, it would be easier to give more targeted advice.

As for your question about the value of `ref`. Scaling constraints to around 1 is a decent starting point. if your nominal constraint value was about 10, then set the ref to 10 and you'd get a scaled value of 1. Id have a look at the actual derivative values though. Are the super tiny? Super massive? As a second iteration of scaling, I normally aim to bring all the derivatives to be within 4 or 5 orders of magnitude of eachother.

One last issue you might consider. Dymos models typically rely heavily on the [total derivative coloring](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.17.0/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/simul_derivs.html?highlight=declare_coloring) for good performance. There are some relevant papers on why this is valuable [here](https://openmdao.org/pubs/openmdao_bicoloring.pdf) and [here](https://openmdao.org/pubs/falck_dymos_2019_scitech.pdf). The coloring system relies heavily on sparsity information provided by the partial derivatives of components. Depending on how you provided your partials (perhaps as dense matricies with diagonal values) you might be getting bad coloring. To sanity check this, you can turn off the total derivative coloring and re-run your optimization. If it works, that gives you a hint. Id consider [switching to sparse partial derivatives](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7c4UJ-meHNY) at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm fairly confident in the partials, but I'll have to go back and double check those. I can confirm that the solvers are not an issue. My ODE is quite complex, so I'll save you the trouble of parsing it.

Comment: For changing ref to have derivatives within 4 to 5 orders of magnitude. Are the derivatives the `collocation_constraint.defect:state_name`. in the scaling report?

Comment: I have not looked into the coloring much. Nearly all of my partials are sparse diagonal matrices, like you showed in the video. Thanks for the advice. I'll see what works.

Comment: All the relevant derivatives are in the scaling report.

Comment: Thanks for all the recommendations. I believe I've identified the issue. I have an implicit component in my model with a newton nonlinear solver and direct linear solver. It appears that the implicit component has 2 solutions that satisfy the residual equations. However, only 1 of those 2 solutions is 'feasible' for the model dynamics. Based on my initial conditions for the states and controls, the solver tends to drive the solution towards the dynamically infeasible solution. When the dynamically infeasible solution is used, it drives the states of the system to violate constraints.

Comment: In the past, I've addressed similar issues by adding constraints on the outputs of the implicit component so the solver would converge to the correct solution. However, I can't get that to work. I tried specifying a linesearch [link](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.16.0/features/building_blocks/solvers/newton.html?highlight=newtonsolver), but that didn't work either. I thought I read about this issue and a solution in the documentation somewhere, but I can't manage to find it again. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: you might try using the `guess_nonlinear` method, either ar the group level or the component level: https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/core_features/working_with_groups/guess_method.html